# Getting individual level scores from factor analysis with lots of missing data

Tags: missing-data, factor-analysis

I have a setting where I'm doing factor analysis in a context where I have lots of rows and where ~90% of data is missing (it's a survey of a couple hundred thousand people, each person was asked a random ten questions (two from every big five domain) out of ~200 items for length reasons).

Estimating the factor model is pretty straight forward:

```
fa_result <- fa(dat_sapa, nfactors = 5, use = "pairwise", rotate = "oblimin", scores="tenBerge")
```

But it seems like the psych package doesn't really work for generating scores if you have missing data (there's an option to score with median/mean imputation, but that would be pretty bonkers in this setting).

Does anyone have any suggestions for how I can generate factor analysis scores in a way that is a good fit for the high levels of sparsity?

Comment: I'm confused by your first sentence, which is likely the key part of this question. Why is there missingness based on subsetting? I would elaborate on this a bit because it seems almost that the missingness is completely artificial.

Comment: That is a great comment, thank you - made edits to clarify.

Comment: Why were they asked questions randomly in the first place?

Comment: The exact data generating process was that there was a desire to collect big five data on a larger survey but there was only space for ten questions, so we randomly sampled two items per domain from a large item bank rather than pick two specific items because we thought it'd give us more flexibility down the line.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sorry but I'm not optimistic.  A factor structure ought to hold for the typical person.  In your case, there is no person for whom you can say anything about the relationships among the 200 variables or even among some key subset of 15 or 20 of them.  To infer the broad patterns among the items, you would need to make what I think are unjustified assumptions about each person's near-interchangeability with the next.

Imputation might come up as a fleeting thought, but what lay person, let alone statistician, would trust findings for which the vast majority of values had been imputed?

Assessing pairwise correlations might be the best you can do to understand these relationships.

Comment: You can feed pairwise correlations into the psych package and recover item parameters that look pretty reasonable to me. The question to me is how to recover factor scores for individual people.